# How to run a docker image on local system which has been deployed on a subpath?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I've my react app deployed at subpath `"/dashboard"`. I achieved this by using `"homepage":"/dashboard"` in `package.json`. And then created a docker image for the same.

Now when I try to run it on my system using that docker image, it shows me this error `http://localhost:3030/dashboard/favicon.ico`

Port 3030 is where my docker container currently running at.

I tried using nginx reverse proxy. But it doesn't seems to be working

My nginx.conf file for reverse proxy

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name localhost;

location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
location /dashboard/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030/;
}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}
```

My docker-compose file

```
version: '3.6'

services:
   explorer:
     image: my-image
     ports:
       - 3030:80

    web:
     image: nginx
     ports:
       - 80:80
    volumes:
       - ../nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Here's the error it gives when I try to access it
[image]

enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Config Error

Change

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/3030;
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030/;
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks for pointing it out.  but that was a typo while writing question.
It gives me this error

`An error occurred.
Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

Faithfully yours, nginx.`

Comment: show me a screenshot

Comment: Added in main question

Comment: also a screen shot of http://127.0.0.1:3030 and your /var/log/nginx/error.log (or wherever it is) from within the container

Comment: Updated in main question

Comment: it looks like something is wrong from `explorer` container side, not nginx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251623/discussion-between-sahil-jangra-and-janithcooray).